# Laravel - Show db data based on select options

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel

I am new to laravel so excuse me if this is a stupid / obvious question - I will remove if so...

i have a drop down list which displays a variety of flavours for an item all sourced from the database. I have this part working fine, however what I want is when you select a flavour, this then displays below the nutritional information for that flavour and changes when you change the flavour.

This is the select in the blade:

```
    <select name="" id="">

        @foreach($flavours as $flavour)

        <option>{{ $flavour['name'] }}</option>

        @endforeach
        
    </select>
```

Simple controller function to get data:

```
function show()
    {
        $data = Flavours::all();
        return view('flavours', ['flavours' => $data]);
    }
```

I have searched online quite alot to find methods / videos which show what I need, however I can not find anything.

Comment: From what you described you need an AJAX request (XMLHttpRequest). With JS you need to catch change event on select element and call backend with that specific id/name of the flavor to get information.
Another option is to use Eloquent and fetch info for every flavor and print it somewhere on page with css display none and on change show that info.

Comment: Search online some more. Keywords that would help would be "laravel load data on select change" (which finds results like [like this one](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-load-employee-name-based-on-dropdown-change))

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways.
1 -  you have to get new data via ajax every change select tag value.
2 - If you don't like it, you can get needed data using keyword and full list.

```html
    <select name="flavour" id="flavour">

        @foreach($flavours as $flavour)

        <option value="{{$flavour['id']}}" >{{ $flavour['name'] }}</option>

        @endforeach
        
    </select>


$("#flavour").change(function(){
  id=$(this).val();
  const flavour_list = <?php echo $flavours; ?>;
  const goal = flavour_list.find(item => item.id === id);
  console.log({goal})
});
```